# Windows: Selecting a file to open through command prompt in a GUI based application which uses a GUI-based open file window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to create a batch script to deliver an instruction to an application to open a file instead of using my mouse to click Open File -> and then manually selecting it (app has a GUI and no native command line support I am aware of, although it is open source and I have the code available to me).

Basically, all this script needs to do is to fill out a field in the application which has a total of two fields. I am trying to figure out a way to do this with no input from the user apart from execution of the command.

If anyone could help with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried simply executing the file with the program, this does not work. I also determined through the source code that the program defines the path variable as "WDL_String variable", although I am not quite sure what to do with this information.

Comment: *the program defines the path variable as "WDL_String variable"* - Is the value of the variable the path to the file which is chosen after the clicking on the Open file? Also, if you have the source code for the application, is there anything in it that says the application can be run with command line arguments? For example, you can open a `*.txt` file from cmd with something like `notepad C:\path\to\your\textfile.txt`. Perhaps you can do the same with your `*.exe`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway have tried the method you described in the second part of your post, it doesn't work. The source code describes the path string as such. It first defines the path as myPath(). It then uses the following code.

```WDL_String initFileName;
      WDL_String initPath(this->myPath.remove_filepart());
      pGraphics->PromptForFile(
          initFileName, initPath, EFileAction::Open, "zip",
          [&](const WDL_String &fileName, const WDL_String &path) {```

To open a dialog box and allow you to choose your file. I want to populate the path by command line instead.

Comment: If that's the case, then I don't think it's possible. At least, not without: 1) using some sort of a a third party automation tool, or 2) building the project (if you have it as, for example, a complete Visual Studio project) after changing the way the `WDL_String` works.